# Programmable bluetooth button for Android and iOS

Tags: android, bluetooth, apple

I'm trying to develop a mobile app that use physical bluetooth button to interact with the app and invoke one (or more) functions.
I found two possible solutions

1. Use media button and emulate media app behavior within my app. It results in strange behavior when my app is off and then phone vols up, starts music etc.
2. Use Flic that uses their button and their app as a proxy for the button. You have to define bahavior in the Flic app that invokes bahavior in your app. The limitation here is Flic proxy app that must be installed and used.

Is there any other solution? Which way I should go if I look for a button that:

- will be stable and robust (no hacks)
- will be able to order less than 100 pcs
- will be programmed especially for my app
- will have nice SDK support
- will work with Android and iOS app

Thanks!